# What kind of binary-to-text encoding is this?

Tags: text, encoding, character-encoding, binary-data, radix

Do you know this binary-to-text encoding?:

qEjv4crWI3owrhkxtNBAuQTyQqP0OQmoJfYH4g3BrJFipxAWefnracua0b5kiio4gq2sSdE82BhI308CRIA/TA==

Superficially it looks like Base64, it even uses a == padding at the end of the string. nonetheless, it is using a '\' character too. I used to believe it was escaping the '/' character, but no, it doesn't.

Any ideas?

Comment: Where is the `\\` character that you mention? I cannot see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a Base64 encoded value. '/' and '+' are part of the base64 alphabet.  A-Za-z0-9 only gets you 62 characters.

Comment: If you decode it as base64 you get gibberish so I'm thinking this is either not base64 or it's malformed base64

Comment: @CharlieHeflin why would you expect to see ascii?  Base64 is just another way of representing number

Comment: Well being that he mentioned it was text I was expecting to see some text rather than what appeared to be gibberish